# How to pre-provision OneDrive for Business "programmatically" for a newly created O365 group?

Tags: office365, office365api

I'm developing a APP with O365 Graph API 1.0.
My scenario is to first create a new group, and then create a folder under the root of the group's drive. But I got the response. How to pre-provision OneDrive for Business "programmatically" for a newly created O365 group?

```
{"data":
{"error":
{"code":"ResourceNotFound",
"message":"Unable to provision resource.",
"innerError":{"request-id":"b795b918-0e24-4193-b6e2-21f2c45de9ec","date":"2015-12-24T08:15:27"}}},"status":404,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/myorganization/groups/01c18c7d-24c6-4a62-993a-d503da7e57ba/drive/root/children","data":{"name":"onedrive","folder":{}},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Authorization":"Bearer eyJ0e","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Not Found"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can provision OneDrive for Business personal sites using the PowerShell cmdlet `Request-SPOPersonalSite` from the SharePoint Online Management Shell. I have a walkthrough on how to use the cmdlet here [Provision OneDrive for Business Personal Sites](http://www.thinkscape.com/Provision-OneDrive-For-Business-Personal-Sites/)